# How to find file on commercial OneDrive?

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I'm using a macro to generate a file list. The macro works on a local drive and a personal OneDrive. It is not able to find any file when the target folder is a commercial OneDrive.

This code is part of a master code and has been pasted here as a sample. I have userforms and hence have not brought in the entire code.

```vb
Public Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        
        ' display file properties
        Cells(iRow, 2).Formula = iRow - 1
        Cells(iRow, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(iRow, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
        Cells(iRow, 5).Formula = Int(FileItem.Size / 1024)
        Cells(iRow, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
        Cells(iRow, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
        Cells(iRow, 8).Select
        Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        FileItem.Path, TextToDisplay:="Click Here to Open"
        
        'Cells(iRow, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"
        
        iRow = iRow + 1 ' next row number
    Next FileItem
        
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If
            
    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
               
End Sub
```

I use the following code to call the macro

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    MsgBox "We will add a new workbook to generate the list.", vbOKOnly, "Generate files message"

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Workbooks.Add

    ActiveSheet.Name = "Index"

    Cells(1, 2).Value = "#"
    Cells(1, 3).Value = "File Name"
    Cells(1, 4).Value = "File Path"
    Cells(1, 5).Value = "File Size ( in KBs )"
    Cells(1, 6).Value = "File Type"
    Cells(1, 7).Value = "Last Modified"
    Cells(1, 8).Value = "Click to Open the File"

    iRow = 2
    fPath = TextBox1.Text

    If fPath <> "" Then
        
        Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        If FSO.FolderExists(fPath) <> False Then
            Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(fPath)
            
            IsSubFolder = True
            If SourceFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox "No files exists in this Folder" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Check your folder path and Try Again !!", vbInformation, "File Manager"
                Exit Sub
            End If
           
            Call ListFilesInFolderXtn(SourceFolder, IsSubFolder)
            
        Else
            MsgBox "Selected Path Does Not Exist !!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Select Correct One and Try Again !!", vbInformation, "File listing"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Folder Path Can not be Empty !!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "", vbInformation, "File listing"
    End If
    
    Unload Me

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    Columns("B:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim formattable As Range

    Set formattable = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, formattable, , xlYes)
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"

End Sub
```

Comment: I have checked that my filename now shows http/www format. If there is a way to isolate that to being the parent folder name, that would be helpful too

Comment: You can't use FSO to enumerate folders on a http path.  You'd need to use the Sharepoint API for something like that.